# How do we check our status on badges?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, badges

On badges like 'sportsmanship' (upvoting 100 competing answers), how do we go about checking our status on these things? I partially assume these statuses are hidden by design to keep people from just gaming the system. However, if there is a way to look further into our own voting (per the example), or to otherwise check on the status of achieving a badge could someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way short of going through your entire history by hand and reviewing your voting. Or you could have planned ahead and recorded your votes as you went.

Comment: lol, Well I'm not going to go that far to contrive badges :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is actually somewhat difficult for the system to display. You'll notice that when you "earn" a badge you don't get it right away. The calculations are being done by another application running in the background. It could take hours before you get the badge. For this reason, displaying everyone's progress in real time is probably outside the architectural design of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

is this information not available in the data dump? (is there even a data dump for our site?)

Could you write a program to parse the data in the dump to find out...

Comment: I don't have any idea, the only data dump I know about happens at 5:01p M-F when I leave work.

Comment: As far as I know, only the original trilogy sites get data dumps.  Not that it would be of much help to an average cook anyway. :P